# Content using {% include %} not appearing on detailed page Django

Tags: python, django

## **UPDATE #4**

Issue: I've been having trouble have content appear on my detailed page view, specifically, this content is in two separate html files called `slider.html` and `sidebar.html`, which are being pulled in using `{% include %}` in Django.

**Status:** *Issue still unresolved, last update on Thurs. Dec 18, 11 a.m.*

- I've made changes to my `models.py` and my `detailed.html`
- Yes, the detailed.html page does have empty divs with classes on them
- I've included my views.py in the main post.

### views.py

```
from django.views import generic
from . import models 
from .models import FullArticle

# Create your views here.
class BlogIndex(generic.ListView):
    queryset = models.FullArticle.objects.published()
    template_name = "list.html" 
    randomArticle = FullArticle.objects.order_by('?').first()

class BlogDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = models.FullArticle
    template_name = "detailed.html"
```

### **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

# Create your models here.
class FullArticleQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def published(self):
        return self.filter(publish=True)

class FullArticle(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    pubDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    heroImage = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    relatedImage =  models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    body =  models.TextField()
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    gameRank = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)

    objects = FullArticleQuerySet.as_manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("FullArticle_detailed", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['object_list'] = models.FullArticle.objects.published()
        return context

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Blog entry"
        verbose_name_plural = "Blog Entries"
        ordering = ["-pubDate"]
```

### **detailed.html**

```
<!-- This grabs the sidebar snippet -->
    {% include "sidebar.html" with object_list=object_list %}

    <div class="mainContent clearfix">
        <h1>{{object.title}}</h1>
        <p class="date">{{object.pubDate|date:"l, F j, Y" }}</p> | <p class="author">{{object.author}}</p>
        <img src="{{object.heroImage}}" alt="" class="largeImage">
        <div class="contentBlock">
            <img src="{{object.relatedImage}}" alt="" class="relatedImage">

            <p class="content">{{object.body|linebreaks}}</p>
        </div><!-- /.contentBlock -->

        <!-- This grabs the slider snippet -->
        {% include "slider.html" with object_list=object_list%}

    </div><!-- /.mainContent -->
```

### **sidebar.html**

```
    <div class="navContent">
        {% for article in object_list|slice:":5" %}
        <div class="navItem">
            <div class="overlay">
            </div><!-- /.overlay -->
                <a href="{%url "detailed" slug=article.slug %}"><img src="{{article.relatedImage}}" alt="" class="navPicture"></a>
            <a href="{%url "detailed" slug=article.slug %}"><p class="navTitle">{{ article.title|truncatewords:"4" }}</p></a>
        </div><!-- /.navItem -->
        {% endfor %}
    </div><!-- /.navContent -->
```

### **urls.py** (which relates to the app called blog)

```
 from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', views.BlogIndex.as_view(), name="list"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>\S+)', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name="detailed"),
)
```

Comment: What does your BlogDetail view look like?

Comment: @dustinfarris I've included my views.py in the main post.

Comment: @dustinfarris Any thoughts on what it could be?

Comment: I've added an answer, hopefully it helps.  Feel free to comment if anything doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm reading through it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_context_data` method belongs in your view.  If you move it there, your sidebar should work.

**However**, there is a much cleaner way to achieve this by using a context processor.  Context processors allow you to make certain data available to *all* of your templates, no matter where they are.

Create `context_processors.py` in your project module directory, and make it look something like this:

```
# myproject/myproject/context_processors.py

from myapp.models import FullArticle


def sidebar_articles(request):
    """Return the 5 most recent articles for the sidebar."""
    articles = FullArticle.objects.all()[:5]
    return {'SIDEBAR_ARTICLES': articles}
```

You will have to enable the context processor in your `settings.py`.  Do this by adding the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` [default setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS), and appending your new context processor to the bottom.  Like this:

```
# settings.py

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
  "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
  "django.core.context_processors.debug",
  "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
  "django.core.context_processors.media",
  "django.core.context_processors.static",
  "django.core.context_processors.tz",
  "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
  "myproject.context_processors.sidebar_articles",
)
```

Now you will be able to reference `SIDEBAR_ARTICLES` from any of your templates.  Your `sidebar.html` could be rewritten as:

```
<!-- myapp/templates/detailed.html -->

<div>
  {% for article in SIDEBAR_ARTICLES %}
  <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
  and so on ...
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Altough it is cleaner and it works, pay attention to the amount of queries you use to fill your context. As mentioned, the variable is available now with every view. Altough one query is not really a problem, but 20 extra queries every time a view loads would be bothersome.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is necessary to pass the right arguments to your included template. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include for more documentation.

Template will probally look like: `{% include "sidebar.html" with article=object %}`

**Update 1**
After reading the docs about detailview, my following suggestions
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) It appears your context only contains a `object`. So we have to pass this to this included slider template.

```
{% include "slider.html" with article=object %}
```

The problem within your sidebar template is that you don't have an object_list within your context. You can add this to your DetailView as shown in the example. So the method would look like.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(BlogDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['object_list'] = models.FullArticle.objects.published()
    return context
```

And the include of the template should look like.

```
{% include "sidebar.html" with object_list=object_list %}
```

Comment: I've tried including {% include "sidebar.html" article=object %} in my detailed.html and it did not work. I would get an error TemplateSyntaxError at /gone-home
Unknown argument for u'include' tag: u'article=object'.

Comment: Sorry @AndrewNguyen, I missed the `with`, I adjusted my answer.

Comment: No dice on that one either using "with". Also flipped it to see if object=article would work. No change, still not appearing.

Comment: @AndrewNguyen, I updated the answer. Could you give this a try?

Comment: You added it to your BlogDetail model, right? If you did, I need some more info. Like what is the url your are using? What is the url in `urls.py`? Also, are the divs imported propperly? So does the resulted page contains divs with the classes `navContent` and `slider`?

Comment: I've updated the main post above for how my content looks now. I've added in my urls.py. There are empty divs with classes basically.

Comment: I've included my views.py in the main post.

Answer (score 0):

Take care you are passing correctly your context to template. But probably you have to add spaces between '{{' bracket and variable name. Ex. {{ article.title }}

Comment: Could you expand on your answer more, don't really think it's a matter of spacing.

Comment: Spacing doesn't matter.